# First names or surnames?

Tags: american-english, politeness

Writing out an interview with two Americans, in US English. It's an interview with 'brothers and sisters in the field' of medicine, semi-scientific, slightly formal but in a friendly kind of way. So in my native Dutch, I'd use first names, as in:

```
John: "Yes, but..."
Mary: "What..."
```

I have this hunch that in US English, this is considered *not done*, even though in everyday life they would John & Mary all the time. So it would  have to be:

```
Smith: "Yeah, well..."
Jones: "What he..."
```

Is my hunch wrong?

Edit: The *not done* bit implies that I want to avoid offending interviewees and readers. Perhaps I should have asked for the 'most neutral form', but I didn't think of the problem like that, at first.

Comment: Frankly, this is less about the English language and usage than about cultural differences and etiquette. The Q may get closed.

Comment: Is this really about the English language *per se*?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's soliciting style advice, rather than addressing the nuts and bolts of grammar and semantics. Doubtless both styles have been used; which is preferable is a matter of opinion.

Comment: @All, I accept your points, but cultural differences and etiquette IMHO play an important role in usage of any language. If you want to restrict this Q&A to 'nuts and bolts of grammar and semantics', OK, but don't you think that's a limit you'll regret at one point or another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In transcripts the names often repeat many times, so it is common to use 2-letter identifiers for each person, and to give a key at the top of the document.

So at the top you could show a key: JS = John Smith, MJ = Mary Jones.

```
JS: "Yeah, well..."
MJ: "What he..."
```

If it's less formal, like a blog article, I recommend using given names over surnames.

Also, first name is an ambiguous term because first names are sometimes surnames, and there are some people who when asked "what is your first name?" will tell you their surname.

Comment: But that's not the question.

Comment: @Jimmy Smith, Thanks, I think it *is* a good answer to the question, as it circumvents the problem of how to not offend the reader and the interviewees. The 'not done' bit. I disagree with the downvote.